# Can i introduce a getter into a Typescript setter?

Tags: typescript

Im trying to introduce a getter into a setter but i cant, anyone can tell me how to do it? Thanks

```
get bday(): string {
  if (this.day) {
    return `${`00${this.day}`.slice(-2)}/${`00${this.month}`.slice(-2)}/${
    this.year }`
    } else {
      return ''
    }
  }

set bday( ){
    this.bday = get bday();
  }
```

Comment: A setter without a value/parameter doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to set the `day`, `month` and `year` variables when using the `bday` setter? If so it won't be that easy, you'll have to parse it properly.

Comment: yes, im trying to use my getter to set my bday

Comment: There's `String.prototype.padStart()` which would make it a little more obvious what you're doing (imho) -> `return \`${this.day.padStart(2, "0")}/${this.month.padStart(2, "0")}/${this.year.padStart(2, "0")}\`;`

Comment: okay thanks, but how can i set the bday attribute automatically with that getter?

Comment: Just don't. The clue is in the name. ***A getter should never mutate its subject.***